# How to include constructor arguments in bytecode for smart contract deployment in genesis block?

Tags: solidity, contract-deployment, private-blockchain, compilation, genesis

Please excuse if the title is not perfectly accurate but I had a hard time fitting my problem into 1 question. If you have a better title please feel free to suggest it and i will edit it.

I want to "deploy" a smart contract in the genesis file of my blockchain so that the contract is available when creating the chain.

Problem: The smart contract requires a constructor argument that I have to include in the bytecode.
When I compile the smart contract in Remix with the arguments set, it works perfectly fine.

Unfortunately, I'm working on a Ubuntu VM so using Remix to compile the contract is not an option.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it programmatically via web3.js (tested with v1.2.1):

```
const Web3 = require("web3");

const web3 = new Web3();
const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(YourAbiArray);
const options = {data: YourByteCode, arguments: [YourArgs]};
const transaction = contract.deploy(options);
console.log(transaction.encodeABI());
```

Note that `YourByteCode` should start with `0x`.